# MySQL,Use command line Or GUI tools

Tags: java, mysql

I am a java programmer for 2 years.

My programs usually uses a database (mysql) (Java SE).

Should i use classically command line environment or use GUI tools, mysql administrator for example?

Is it necessary to be a database administrator? Or not?

I want to be a java programmer.

Sorry for this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of GUI tools, IDE's is very common in IT industry also makes life easier as they have very good features to detect bad usage of the programming language, bad syntaxis, illegal uses of the language and pretty cool stuff as refactor options just to said one of them.

I encourage for people that are starting or want to achieve an IT certification (SCJP) not use in their training lesson, sometimes people know the error only because IDE's is complaining about something and does not really know what is the root cause, so remove GUI or IDE will help you a lot in really know the root cause of the problems and give you really good troubleshooting skills.

Talking about SQL language, although you want to become java programmer, SQL need to be one of your skills, I'm strongly suggest learn it without use of GUI or SQL creators, also is not bad to know by memory some really most frequently used commands and know the solutions just using command line. I know a lot of people in IT that does not how to create an insert statement in sql and its variants as they always use MySQL to add records.